# How to save data in custom table from default form in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I wanna save data from forms created using liferay 7 drag and drop feature in custom table not in default table of liferay.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own StorageAdapter.

Storage adapters are configured for **new forms** that do not have any data submitted. The setting is a bit hidden in Control panel > Form > New Form > Settings (top right corner) > Select storage type.

You can have a look at [JSONStorageAdapter](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-dynamic-data-mapping/blob/master/dynamic-data-mapping-service/src/main/java/com/liferay/dynamic/data/mapping/storage/impl/JSONStorageAdapter.java) on how to implement a new storage adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Additional documentation about howto write your custom storage adapter (as OSGI component) can be found in the [Forms Storage Adapters](https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/forms-storage-adapters) documentation page of Liferay Develper Network.